# Ошибка при попытке создать React-native проект

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

Использую комманду:
    create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
После перехожу в проект:
    cd awesomeproject
Далее:
    npm run eject 
Чтобы скомпилировать файлы для AndroidStudio
Версия ноды: 8.9.4
Версия npm: 5.6.0
Вот что пишет консоль:

```
Не удается найти пакетный файл.
Не удается найти пакетный файл.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.1.0 eject: `react-native-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pebah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-09T06_24_26_525Z-debug.log
```

Вот что в [лог файле](https://text-share.com/view/16bdf21e):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'eject' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'preeject', 'eject', 'posteject' ]
5 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~preeject: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: AwesomeProject@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\work\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\pebah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\pebah\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\pebah\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;C:\Users\pebah\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
9 verbose lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: CWD: F:\work\AwesomeProject
10 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native-scripts eject' ]
11 silly lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle AwesomeProject@0.1.0~eject: Failed to exec eject script
13 verbose stack Error: AwesomeProject@0.1.0 eject: `react-native-scripts eject`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid AwesomeProject@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd F:\work\AwesomeProject
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "eject"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error AwesomeProject@0.1.0 eject: `react-native-scripts eject`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.1.0 eject script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md#ejecting-from-create-react-native-app), убедитесь что установлен `react-native-cli` глобально перед тем как делать `eject`. Должно помочь.